# Is the set of the rational numbers equal to the set of periodic numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, rational-numbers

Is $\mathbb Q = \{\text{set of all numbers periodic from some point on}\}$ ?

I am pretty sure that $\{\text{set of all numbers periodic from some point on}\} \subset \mathbb Q$ but i don't know how to prove.

I didn't find any proof about $\mathbb Q \subset \{\text{set of all numbers periodic from some point on}\}$. Maybe it is wrong.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Is $0.5$ or $1$ a periodic number?

Comment: @player3236 $.5=.49999\dots$, so I would say, "Yes".

Comment: @saulspatz The 4 there is destroying the strict sense of periodic/recurring.

Comment: That is why I inquire whether $0.5$ or $1$ is periodic: I don't know what the definition of "periodic numbers" is.

Comment: Well. I would say no because technicaly. 1 is never being repeated. However 0 is being repeated. I think i will add what i mean by "periodic".

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, but I think the OP must mean "periodic from some point on."

Comment: Also $.5 = .500000\ldots$

Comment: @player3236 Well, I admit I'm guessing.